# inverse Laplace transform of an integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, inverse-laplace

find $$u(x,t)$$ Given
$$ U(x,s)=\frac{s+2}{(s+1)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)cosh((s+1)(x-y))dx}$$
where U is the Laplace transform of the function u.

I tried substituting $$cosh((s+1)(x-y))=\frac{e^{(s+1)(x-y)} +e^{-(s+1)(x-y)}}{2}$$
but Im not sure how to proceed after this